# bashscript for changing wput uploaddirectory on every 5000 passage

Tags: bash, shell

how i can change the uploaddirectory of wput on every 5000 passage?
whats wrong in my code?

only for the record; i need infnite loop i want run this script 24h 365 days!
every 5000 passage one number higher in directory like incoming1-infinite

best regards

haug

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( ; ; ))
do
  no=1
  while [ $no -le 5000 ]
  do
    perl job.pl false false 1
    cd comp

    for fname in *.jpg;
    do
      mv -i "$fname" ${RANDOM}${RANDOM}.jpg
    done

    for fname in *.jpg;
    do
      mv "$fname" $(echo "$fname" | sha1sum | cut -f1 -d' ').jpg
    done

    if [ $no = '5000' ]
    then
      echo $no
      echo $n
      n=$(( n+1 )) # <-- this one not do what i need :-(

    else
      wput *.jpg ftp://user:pass@ip:port/incoming$n/  # <-- here is the important part 2, i need it to change one directory higher every 5000 passage for example; incoming1 until   infinite       
      rm  -rf *.jpg
      cd ..
    fi

    no=`expr $no + 1`
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd comp
for ((no=1; ; no++))
do
  n=`expr $no / 5000`

  perl job.pl false false 1

  for fname in *.jpg;

  # ... rest of the script
done
```

Comment: thank you too , you script running well i keep this in mind with  n=`expr $no / 5000` (--:

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the remainder of division by 5000 and if it is equal 0 (or 1 or anything < 5000) do what you need.

```
if [ $((no%5000)) = 0 ]
then
...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a for-loop that executes 5,000 times inside your infinite loop (which can keep track of the directory sequence number for you):

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( n=0; ; n++ )); do
  for (( no=1; no < 5000; no++ )); do
    perl job.pl false false 1
    ( # Subshell so we don't have to worry about returning
      # to the previous directory.
      cd comp

      # No need to rename each file twice.
      for fname in *.jpg; do
        mv "$fname" $(echo "${RANDOM}${RANDOM}.jpg" | sha1sum | cut -f1 -d' ').jpg
      done

      wput *.jpg ftp://user:pass@ip:port/incoming$n
    )
  done      
done
```

Comment: works well thank you very much. and thank you for thte short rename line with | operator, i forget that :-)